# Value of Infinite Geometric Sum

Tags: calculus, integration

For this question I tried using the formula $a/(1-r)$ where a is the first term and r is the ratio (current term divided by previous) but I keep getting the wrong answer. The question was:

$5(0.2)^3 +5(0.2)^4+5(0.2)^5+...+5(0.2)^9$

Comment: What is the answer you got and how did you get it? The formula you have written is for an infinite sum and the given sum has only $7$ terms.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an infinite sum. It's a finite sum.

The formula for the finite geometric sum is $S_n = \frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$.

$a =5 (0.2)^3=0.04,r=0.2, n=7$

That works out (exactly) to $0.04999936$.